# What is the proper way to make a data process request with Ember data?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I am making a flash card app and the business logic is implemented in the backend.

The previous version I use jquery to fetch data and make request between server and client (see below),

```
getNextCard() {
    const {URL, headers} = this._getParams('/next_card');

    return Ember.$.ajax(URL, {
        method: "GET",
        headers
    });
},

submitAnswer(card) {
    const {URL, headers} = this._getParams('/process_card');

    return Ember.$.ajax(URL, {
        method: "POST",
        headers,
        data: card
    });
},
```

I have changed to Ember data in the the current version; however, I am so confusied and do not know what is the proper way to make this kind of request with Ember data.

Should I continue using `Ember.$.ajax` to make data process request (like code above) and using Ember data solely for data/model CRUD prupose?

**Update**

After dig through the documentation, I think `getNextCard` method can be accomplish by customizing the adapter.

https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/models/customizing-adapters/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to represent this as CRUD operations. It's a bit another way of thinking.

So you could for example set the answer on the record, and then just `.save()` the record. Or have another `answer` model, and create an `answer` and save that. Depends a bit on the specific requirements of your application.

To retrieve the next card just use `store.query()`. So that you basically can do something like `store.query('card', { next: true })`, and implement this in your adapter accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much for the hints. :D